# date() in [angular-ui datepicker directive] returns yesterday's date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui

I have date picker using [angular-ui datepicker directive](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker), however when I select a date it shows me the previous day. And tried it via console, the result remains.

I don't get the main reason behind this issue.

[image: Date]

Comment: you select date correct, but angular convert date to based on time zone, 
selected date as time 22:00:00.000Z and you got GMT+0200 i.e 22+2 i.e next day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Date constructor only recognises a few formats when a string is passed to it. You need to use Date.parse which recognises a lot more formats and produces the representation of the passed in date string as the number of milliseconds since the Epoch which, in turn, will be accepted by the constructor and produce the desired date object.

```
var date = new Date(Date.parse("2015-07-27T22:00:00.000Z"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) specifies that you need to pass the date as

```
new Date(year, month[, day[, hour[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]]);
```

So you should pass it as:

```
new Date(2015,07,27,22,00,00,0000000000);
```

or else you need to use the `Date.parse` to parse the date correctly.

**On a side note:** [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) is good to handle all these issues.

Answer (score 0):

May be it seems work for you

```
      <!doctype html>
     <html lang="en">
          <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Display month &amp; year menus</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
     <script>
      $(function() {
       $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
         changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true
      });
         });
    </script>
    </head>
     <body>

   <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>


  </body>
     </html>
```